# Prism and Click Once

Tags: wpf, clickonce, prism

I am interested in how others have done Prism and Click Once.

Specifically, if you have a module/dll that is used in several applications, how do you handle deployment of an update to that module/dll?  Do you have to open up each application and hit Publish?

Also, sometimes, my Prism app does not have references to all the dll's that it uses.  It will just import them via the ModuleCatalog from a file.  Because the project does not see those dlls as references it does not put them in to deploy them.  How do you tell click once to deploy random dlls?

To address the above issue I tried adding all the dlls I was using as a reference to my Shell Project.  But it when I do a build does not even copy all of them to the output directory because it cannot see them being directly used.  This happens most when a module is only used via IEventAggregator.  This (of course) means that when I do a Publish those dlls are missing.

So, am I able to use Click Once for Prism?  Or is it too limited?  Is there a better way?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document seems to have answers to some of the questions I posed (specifically dynamic libraries).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405497%28PandP.40%29.aspx

**Later Note:** I tried the steps in this walk through and they do not work.  (Just to save any one else the heart ache of trying to get it to work.)  You end up with a corrupted deploy.

Comment: @rboarman - but this is an answer.  If I already had an answer then maybe I would update the post.  But since no other answers are forth comming, some answer is better than no answer.  (Look around at other questions and you will see that this is the norm around here.)

Answer (score 1):

It works following [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405497%28PandP.40%29.aspx), the only note is that clickonce should be deployed as offline support application if you selected online the application will crash while trying to load the modules A and C.